# Apache Kafka and apache flink

Tags: android, cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Is a viable and secure architecture for these that is also scalable to thousands of mobile users: the mobile users sending https requests to a rest API which then populates Kafka topics which are then consumed by flink for analytics, then flink stores results in a Cassandra instance keyed by users and then the original mobile producers get real time updates by querying the Cassandra results??

Comment: This is probably fine. I think the point that's most likely to become problematic is having sufficient bandwidth to cassandra. Just think through how many users there might be, how large the analytics will be, and how often they will need to be updated. One million users with 1K bytes of data to be written every second is a very different story from updating thousands of small records every hour.

Comment: What would you suggest to make the updates more efficient?

Comment: Depends on your requirements. If you must have real-time access to analytics that are updated very frequently, then using Flink's queryable state might be appropriate.

Comment: Instead of using a separate processing technology such as Apache Flink, you can also use Kafka's own Streams API to implement the processing/analytics part.  Kafka's Streams API supports interactive queries ("get real-time updates by querying") and, compared to Flink, the interactive queries feature in Kafka is production-ready.  More info at http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/ and https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams (we are currently pushing more content to the Apache Kafka docs on Kafka's Streams API; in the meantime, the first link has more info).